# Jest error: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

Looks Jest cannot transform d.ts files. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
/node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/OverlayTrigger.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      1 | import classNames from 'classnames';
      2 | import React from 'react';
    > 3 | import OverlayTrigger from 'react-bootstrap/esm/OverlayTrigger';
        | ^
```

Also I have this in package.json jest configuration

```
 "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx|d.ts)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.svg$": "<rootDir>/svgTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|d.ts)$",
      "^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ]
```

Comment: Have you checked [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts)' `test` command's configuration?

Comment: You can find the jest transformer [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/config/jest/babelTransform.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were issues with importing esm modules directly in jest => Just change

```
import OverlayTrigger from 'react-bootstrap/esm/OverlayTrigger';
```

to

```
import { OverlayTrigger } from 'react-bootstrap';
```